# why vim-easytags don't highlight my class?

Tags: c++, vim, highlighting

I'm trying to use vim for coding, but i got stuck in this issue. I installed the vim-easytags and i want to highlight my class, but it's only highlighting my structures:

[image]

Here is my .vimtags file:

[image]

It's possible to see that my class Joselito was not tagged.

Anyone knows how to solve this?

Comment: Use the plugin's issue tracker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the class definition is not contained in your `tags` file, the EasyTags plugin cannot be blamed for not highlighting it. Instead, you have to look into why the entry is missing from your `tags` file. Possible causes:

- outdated / buggy version of (I guess you use) Exuberant Ctags
- wrong (C instead of C++) file type detected